# unable to start program QuantLib-vc120-mt-gd.lib

Tags: quantlib

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2013, QuantLib and Boost and have gone through the steps of building the complete quantlib project as per http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml guidelines. 
I created a new project under QuantLib_vc11. 
I both built Quantlib and the project in Debug Mode. No errors.

Then when I try to debug, I have the following error:

> unable to start program QuantLib-vc120-mt-gd.lib_

Do you know where it comes from?

And another question, can we use QuantLib with CodeBlocks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're debugging with the QuantLib project as the startup project. Since 
`QuantLib-vc120-mt-gd.lib` is a library, and not an executable file, the debugger rightly complains that it can't start it.

Before launching the debugger, select your new project as the start-up project instead. (I'm assuming that your new project defines a `main` function and creates an executable, right?)  This will cause the debugger to start your program with QuantLib linked.

As for CodeBlocks: there's no included project for it, but QuantLib works with most (if not all) compilers it supports.  Creating a new project in CodeBlocks and adding all the sources in the `ql` folder should enable you to create QuantLib. Note that you'll have to tell CodeBlocks to create a library; I'm not familiar with the IDE, so I'm not able to advise on how to do that.

Comment: Hello Luigi, thanks a lot for your answer. This was precisely the issue! I started with a new project, not QuantLib project. The main function with some quantlib objects inside worked well. Thanks also for your answer on CodeBlock. I will continue with Visual Studio as it works well now.